# Ignoring bots when tracking events in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I am tracking events through Mixpanel in my Rails app. For example, my controller looks something like

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    track_event "Visitor: View Landing Page"
  end
end
```

The problem is that the app gets hit by a number of bots, most notably Pingdom (performance tracking service we use). Is there a clean way to ignore tracking when it is a bot that hits my app?

*Note: I am interested in tracking unique visitors, so I assign a cookie to each visitor with a unique id. Bots obviously don't store cookies.*

Comment: I didn't use pingdom, but I imagine that you specify an URL for them to load. If yes, include a special `bot=1` parameter in the query string. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the problem is that there are likely other bots visiting that shouldn't be tracked. Examples: google bot, bing bot, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The traditional way to do this is to build an index of bot user agents, and to simply ignore your tracking event code when the UA matches a bot.

```
bots = /Googlebot|Pingdom|.../
unless request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].match(bots)
  track_event(...)
end
```

This is a pain to maintain, but it's generally effective. It obviously isn't effective for anyone lying about their UA, but there's not a lot you can do about that other than doing heuristic detection to determine that they aren't a bot, but that's likely not worth the effort in this case.

Comment: any reason it can't be a whitelist instead of a blacklist? It could only allow user agents such as Mozilla, IE, ipad, etc.

Comment: No reason, except that you're going to end up putting an awful lot of work into building and maintaining a whitelist of valid user agents. They're constantly changing, and there's an utterly mindblowing number of agents in use these days.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 & 4 you can use a gem that enables you to use the old Rails 2 session variable to manage turning on/off sessions easily. Worked great for me:

https://github.com/kares/session_off